# Query a JSONB object array

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I did a DB Fiddle of what the table is kinda looking like https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/3382

Data in the table looks like this

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "form_id": 1,
        "questionnaire_response": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "title": "Are you alive?",
                "value": "Yes",
                "form_id": 0,
                "shortTitle": "",
                "description": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "title": "Did you sleep good?",
                "value": "No",
                "form_id": 0,
                "shortTitle": "",
                "description": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "title": "Whats favorite color(s)?",
                "value": [
                    "Red",
                    "Blue"
                ],
                "form_id": 0,
                "shortTitle": "",
                "description": ""
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "form_id": 1,
        "questionnaire_response": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "title": "Are you alive?",
                "value": "Yes",
                "form_id": 0,
                "shortTitle": "",
                "description": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "title": "Did you sleep good?",
                "value": "Yes",
                "form_id": 0,
                "shortTitle": "",
                "description": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "title": "Whats favorite color(s)?",
                "value": "Black",
                "form_id": 0,
                "shortTitle": "",
                "description": ""
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "form_id": 1,
        "questionnaire_response": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "title": "Are you alive?",
                "value": "Yes",
                "form_id": 0,
                "shortTitle": "",
                "description": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "title": "Did you sleep good?",
                "value": "No",
                "form_id": 0,
                "shortTitle": "",
                "description": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "title": "Whats favorite color(s)?",
                "value": [
                    "Black",
                    "Red"
                ],
                "form_id": 0,
                "shortTitle": "",
                "description": ""
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have a query `select * from form_responses,jsonb_to_recordset(form_responses.questionnaire_response) as items(value text, id text) where (items.id = '3' AND items.value like '%Black%');`

But unable to do more than one object like `select * from form_responses,jsonb_to_recordset(form_responses.questionnaire_response) as items(value text, id text) where (items.id = '3' AND items.value like '%Black%') AND (items.id = '2' AND items.value like '%Yes%');`

The value field in the object could be an array or a single value also.. unpredictable.. I feel like I'm close but also not sure if im using the correct query in the first place.

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT

```
select * from form_responses where(
  questionnaire_response @> '[{"id": "2", "value":"No"},{"id": "3", "value":["Red"]}]')
```

Seems to work but not sure if this is the best way to do it

Comment: Trying to build a filter system where I can dynamically pass multiple ID and value and get the entire record from this [{id: 1, value: 'Yes'},{id: 2, value: 'No'}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current query returns one result row per item. None of these rows has both `id = 3` and `id = 2`. If your goal is to select the entire form response, you need to use a subquery (or rather, two of them):

```
SELECT *
FROM form_responses
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM jsonb_to_recordset(form_responses.questionnaire_response) as items(value text, id text)
    WHERE items.id = '3'
      AND items.value like '%Black%'
  )
  AND EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM jsonb_to_recordset(form_responses.questionnaire_response) as items(value text, id text)
    WHERE items.id = '2'
      AND items.value like '%Yes%'
  );
```

or alternatively

```
SELECT *
FROM form_responses
WHERE (
    SELECT value
    FROM jsonb_to_recordset(form_responses.questionnaire_response) as items(value text, id text)
    WHERE items.id = '3'
  ) like '%Black%'
  AND (
    SELECT value
    FROM jsonb_to_recordset(form_responses.questionnaire_response) as items(value text, id text)
    WHERE items.id = '2'
  ) like '%Yes%';
```

A nicer alternative would be using [json path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM form_responses
WHERE questionnaire_response @@ '$[*]?(@.id == "1").value == "Yes"'
  AND questionnaire_response @@ '$[*]?(@.id == "3").value[*] == "Black"'
-- in one:
SELECT *
FROM form_responses
WHERE questionnaire_response @@ '$[*]?(@.id == "1").value == "Yes" && $[*]?(@.id == "3").value[*] == "Black"'
```

The `[*]` even has the correct semantics for that sometimes-string-sometimes-array value. And if you know the indices of the items with those ids, you can even simplify to

```
SELECT *
FROM form_responses
WHERE questionnaire_response @@ '$[0].value == "Yes" && $[2].value[*] == "Black"'
```

<sup>([dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3bee37568b01fe624156717c4e758942))</sup>

Comment: Getting a 'ERROR:  cannot extract elements from a scalar' when setting ANY jsonb_array_elements_text(value). What would the main reason to use this over the `select * from form_responses where(
  questionnaire_response @> '[{"id": "2", "value":"No"},{"id": "3", "value":["Red"]}]')` query?

Comment: Oh, I see now that even for item 3 the value can be a string and is not always an array - I would have expected the data type to depend on the question you're asking. The benefit would be clearer semantics, "is exactly an element of the array" is a different query than "the string representation of the array somehow contains the substring somewhere".

Comment: Yeah `jsonb_array_elements_text` is not gonna work with that data (unless using very complicated `CASE jsonb_type(value) OF …` expressions). Much better alternative: jsonpath!

Comment: I see your edit! This is awesome! I hadn't looked into jsonpath but this seems exactly what it was built for!

Comment: I like the json path queries and they work well, but one more question on it, how would I go about looking for a value to match like ["Red","Black"] in a unknown order. `SELECT *
FROM form_responses
WHERE questionnaire_response @@ '$[*]?(@.id == "1").value == "Yes"'
  AND questionnaire_response @@ '$[*]?(@.id == "3").value[*] == "Black"'
  AND questionnaire_response @@ '$[*]?(@.id == "3").value[*] == "Red"'` works but not sure if this is the best approach. Again thanks for helping me with this! Was spending too much time on it and I'm new to Postgresql. So far I love it!

Comment: Looks fine to me, but I don't have any experience with jsonpath performance either. I guess you could do something like `questionnaire_response @? '$[*]?(@.id == "3" && @.value[*] == "Red" && @.value[*] == "Black")'` to shorten it.